# Three.js - Creating/Updating a mesh with mouse move and click

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I want to be able to create a Mesh from the users mouse clicks. Every time a user clicks a new point will be added to the mesh. Also when the user moves their mouse the last point should follow their cursor.

I have been able to do this using a Line, whose geometry is a BufferGeometry, where the positions are set as an attribute of the BufferGeometry.

Then when the user clicks I add the x, y coordinates to the positions array and then set the BufferGeometry's drawrange. When the user moves their mouse I am updating the x,y coordinates of the last position and then setting BufferGeometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate to true. This works as well.

However now I now want to be able to use a mesh instead of a line as I want to have an enclosed shape, but am having difficulties with it showing/updating.

Is there an easy approach to updating and adding points to a mesh on mouse click/mouse move?

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxwyem)

```js
let scene, camera, renderer, raycaster, canvas;

let linePositions, lineGeometry, line, myMesh;

let count = 0;

init();
initScene();
animate();

function init() {
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
}

function initScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

  camera.position.z = 5;

  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  initCanvas();
}

/* Initialize the Canvas so we can raycast the mouse click and mouse move */
function initCanvas() {
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(7, 7, 1, 0);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    visible: false
  });

  canvas = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(canvas);

  addLineAndMesh();
}

function addLineAndMesh() {

  linePositions = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(25 * 3), 3).setDynamic(true);

  // geometry
  lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  lineGeometry.addAttribute('position', linePositions);

  // material
  const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    linewidth: 1
  });

  const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    opacity: 0.6
  });

  myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(lineGeometry, material);
  scene.add(myMesh);

  // line
  line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
  scene.add(line);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

function onClick(e) {
  const pos = getMousePosition(e);

  if (count === 0) {
    setPositions(pos, false);
    count++;
  }

  setPositions(pos, false);
  count++;

  lineGeometry.setDrawRange(0, count);
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  const pos = getMousePosition(e);
  setPositions(pos, true);
}

function setPositions(pos, isUpdate) {
  const index = isUpdate ? count - 1 : count;

  linePositions.setXYZ(index, pos.x, pos.y, 0);

  linePositions.needsUpdate = true;
  line.frustumCulled = false;
  myMesh.frustumCulled = false;
}

function getMousePosition(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let mouse = {};
  mouse.x = (e.offsetX / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(e.offsetY / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
  mouse.z = 0;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([canvas]);

  if (intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0]) {
    mouse = intersects[0].point;
  }

  return mouse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You probably won't get any answers until you can add the example. That said, I don't recommend building upon a single mesh. Every time you add points to a geometry object, it has to re-push that buffer to the GPU. Unless you're anticipating THOUSANDS of clicks, it will be more efficient to add and track individual meshes for each shape you add.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Create buffer geometry and mesh from it. Add new 'xyz' to 'position' buffer attribute on each click (mouseup), update it on mousemove (dont forget to set attribute.needsUpdate = true). That's it.

Comment: @TheJim01 I'm working on getting an example up shortly. But I have implemented as per SalientBrain's comment

Comment: @TheJim01 I have now added an example